# Unable draw or render visible on SurfaceView which is on top of another SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

I’m attempting to implement the building blocks off a menu/graphics that I can move across my Apps screen which displays a camera preview.

**My ScanImageBarcodeActivity contains custom SurfaceView named CameraPreview which displays live camera & guidance rectangle for scanning barcodes** (this part works perfectly I'm able to display live video stream & decode barcodes).

I have created another custom **SurfaceView named “OverlayOfSurfaceView”** , which I would like to place on top of CameraPreview, in order draw some graphics & display a menu
The problem is the **“OverlayOfSurfaceView “ onDraw() is only called a several times & I never called again although , therefore I can’t see the test graphic a “blue bar” that is supposed to be drawn.**

What is actually strange is when a stop the camera preview than I see the blue line that Im using to test the onDraw of OverlayOfSurfaceView.

**Below are the relevant parts of my ScanImageBarcodeActivity:**

```
public class ScanImageBarcodeActivity extends Activity {

//removed irrelevant code for this post 

    // onCreate, instantiates layouts & surfaceView used for video preview
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_barcode_vin_scanner);
        Log.d("ClassScanViewBarcodeActivity", "onCreate ");

        // inflate layout will that contain camera preview
        FrameLayoutBarcodeScanner = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutForPreview);

        // inflate surface view that will be on top of camera preview surface
        // view
        surfaceViewLayOver = (OverlayOfSurfaceView) FrameLayoutBarcodeScanner
                .findViewById(R.id.overlay);
        // make the background transparent so the user can see cameraPreview
        // behind surfaceViewLayOver
        surfaceViewLayOver.setAlpha(0);
        // 0 is teh default means visible
        surfaceViewLayOver.setVisibility(0);
        globalContext = this.getApplicationContext();
        // ini all camera & barcode API settings & start preview
        initializeGlobalCamera();

        handler = new Handler();

        /*
         * if surfaceViewLayOver has been instantiated & hopefully inflated
         * create Thread that tries to draw grahics on the canvas of
         * surfaceViewLayOver
         */
        if (surfaceViewLayOver != null) {
            // draw in another thread
            new Thread() {

                public void run() {
                    // while the camera output is being displayed
                    while (cameraPreviewing != false) {
                        // sleep 30 millisecs to control frame/draw rate
                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(30);

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        SurfaceHolder holder = surfaceViewLayOver.getHolder();
                        // get canvas to draw
                        Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

                        try {
                            if (canvas != null) {
                                synchronized (holder) {
                                    // call onDraw of custom SurfaceView
                                    surfaceViewLayOver.onDraw(canvas);

                                }

                            }
                        } finally {
                            if (canvas != null)
                                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                            canvas = null;
                            // yield other threads can render graphics to the
                            // screen
                            // Thread.yield();

                        }

                    }// end while

                }// end run
            }.start();
        } else {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "surfaceViewLayOver is: "
                    + surfaceViewLayOver);
        }
//removed irrelevant code for this post 
    }// end onCreate
}//end activity
```

**The layout, activity_barcode_vin_scanner.xml  is the layout of my Activity & contains layout code for OverlayOfSurfaceView:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LayoutForPreview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    <com.net.app.barcode.OverlayOfSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
      />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Below is my OverlayOfSurfaceView:**

```
package com.net.app.barcode;

import com.net.app.R;

//removed irrelevant code 

public class OverlayOfSurfaceView extends SurfaceView  implements
SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Context context;
    private LinearLayout linearMenu = null; 
    public OverlayOfSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context,attr);
        this.context = context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        linearMenu = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.layout.barcode_scanner_overlay_menu);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


  drawGuidance(canvas);
  super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    public void drawGuidance(Canvas canvas) {

        Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"drawGuidance(Canvas canvas)");
        Paint paintRed = new Paint();
        paintRed.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paintRed.setStrokeWidth(6f);
        paintRed.setAntiAlias(true);
        paintRed.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        // drawMiddleline
        canvas.drawLine(0,this.getHeight()/2,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight()/2 , paintRed);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
         Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"surface created");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events
        // here.


    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
         Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"surface changed");


    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
         Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"surface destroyed");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // empty. Take care of releasing resources here 
    }

}//end class
```

Below is actual snapshot (no blue line drawn on OverlayOfSurfaceView , cant confirm if OverlayOfSurfaceView is drawn/visible although I know "surface was created" via logs).

[image]

The OverlayOfSurfaceView SurfaceView should be draw a blue line on top of CameraPreview like the below pic, **but its not:**

[image]

What are the most likely issues?, If possible be specific & point me to working code.

Thanks a million!

Comment: Did you set the Z ordering on the second SurfaceView?  If you don't, one of them will "win".  (See e.g. Grafika's "multi-surface test" activity, which has three overlapping SurfaceViews.)  https://github.com/google/grafika

Comment: I used the method ``surfaceViewLayOver.bringToFront();``, but no change

Comment: @fadden , I also used ``FrameLayoutBarcodeScanner.bringChildToFront(surfaceViewLayOver);`` but i cant still see any change. I think this may be some kind of threading issue , since the CameraPreview is constantly streaming to the screen, it may never allow other graphics on other Views to post to the hardware & render??? Although I added a Thread.yield(); to the CameraPreview Thread...

Comment: `bringToFront()` affects the View part.  If you have two SurfaceViews, you need to set the Z-order on the Surface part (e.g. `setZOrderOnTop()`).  The View part is just a transparent hole.  Again, see the Grafika code for an example.

Comment: Z ordering did the work for me !!

Comment: @cyber101 were you able to fix the issue... as I'm facing the same??

Comment: @MuahmmadTayyib, yes many years ago. I don't have access to the code anymore, however Android API (specifically related to custom camera) has changed significantly and any answer would almost be irrelevant today.